# Dependent Dropdown using Views

Tags: views, blocks, ajax, theming, taxonomy-terms

I have two select lists, each in its own **Block View**.  The second list should be disabled until you select something from the first, in which case it would be populated based on the selection.  Is there any way to do this using views and contextual filters? Like, pass in a dynamic value as a contextual filter to the second block view?  Or even by using some ajax-based preprocess function?

I've searched and I always see how to do this by using a module, but I was wondering if it were possible to do this just using views because the relationship between the two Terms already exists in my Vocabulary.

Comment: Are they under same webform?

Comment: not using a webform.  should i be?  and can it be broken into mutliple views or should it just be one view?  thanks.

Comment: Sorry I not too sure. If you are using webform, you can use conditional to solve your problem. Since you are not using, you may need java-script to disable list B until list A get some value.